# How do I prevent certain values from being returned in a search query?

Tags: algolia

How do I prevent certain values from being returned in a search query?

For example, I am using the geo-query feature of Algolia and would like to prevent the location from being sent back to the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify **[Unretrievable Attributes](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/security/best-security-practices/#unretrievable-attributes)**: this features lets you select which information of your records should *not* be returned with your search results.

For example with the [JavaScript API Client](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/javascript/getting-started/):

```
index.setSettings({
  unretrievableAttributes: ["_geoloc"]
})
```

Comment: this isn't working for me. It's indexing the results from something I want excluded.

Comment: @LanceSamaria it should work, but maybe you have other settings that interfere. Can you reach out to support@algolia.com so we can investigate your situation?

Comment: thanks for the reply. I reached out to them. I'll post what they sent me below.

Comment: this what they suggested I used and it worked. Maybe the problem I was having wasn't the same as the OP's?

Comment: I think there is a slight confusion: unretrievableAttributes makes sure attributes _that are indexed_ are not returned at search time, while it seems you wanted to avoid indexing these attributes _at all_.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I wasn’t to sure what the exact purpose. Quick question, what is ‘restrictSearchableAttributes’ for?

Comment: It lets you restrict at search time the attributes where the query term are searched. For example you might have `searchableAttributes=['artistName', 'songTitle']` but do a query with `restrictSearchableAttributes=['artistName']` to only search in artist names for that query.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I reached out to Algolia support and they suggested I delete whatever attributes I don't want indexed by deleting it after the objectID is obtained:

```
function addOrUpdateIndexRecord(contact) {

    // Get Firebase object
    const record = contact.val();

    // Specify Algolia's objectID using the Firebase object key. ObjectID is obtained here
    record.objectID = contact.key;

    // Use this to delete the attributes you don't want indexed
    delete record.whateverNameOfTheFirstAttribute
    delete record.whateverNameOfTheSecondAttribute
    delete record.whateverNameOfTheThirdAttribute
    delete record.etcEtc

    // Add or update object
    index
      .saveObject(record)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Firebase object indexed in Algolia', record.objectID);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error when indexing contact into Algolia', error);
        process.exit(1);
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: This works if you want to actually remove the attributes from your index, while the OP wanted to **have these attributes indexed** (e.g. for ranking) **but not returned in a search query**.